# Get username with queryBuilder join using FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I use FOSUserBundle, and I need to get the user names who wrote comments on my post.

I use function `createQuery` to get the post comments, and add this join to trying to get the names:

```
<?php

namespace CommentsBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User;

/**
 * CommentsRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class CommentsRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function getPostComments($planId)
    {
        $arrPlanComments = array();

        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(

            'SELECT 
             c.id, 
             c.fkUser, 
             c.fkReply, 
             c.comment, 
             c.createdAt, 
             c.likes, 
             c.unlikes 
             FROM CommentsBundle:Comments c 
             INNER JOIN UserBundle:User u 
             WITH (c.fkUser = u.id) 
             WHERE 
             c.fkPlan = :planId 
             ORDER BY c.createdAt DESC'

        )->setParameter('planId', $planId);

        try
        {
            $arrPlanComments = $query->getArrayResult();
        }
        catch(\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }

        return $arrPlanComments;
    }

}
```

I have extended the FOSUserBundle to my custom bundle named 'UserBundle', and it works fine, but I don't know how to add the relationship with this entity.

I am having this error when i add the join relationship:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 164 near 'UserBundle:User': Error: Class 'UserBundle\Entity\User' is not defined.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, you have to [create own class](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#step-3-create-your-user-class) for User entity, which will extend one provided by FOSUser. It seems like you haven't done that. That's what your error message probably indicates.

Comment: Thanks bro, it works!. I forgot that installation step.  ; )